# An object can `respond_to` a message but raise an error when called?

Tags: ruby, clone, deep-copy

I tried:

```
1.respond_to? "clone"    # => true
1.clone                  # => TypeError: can't clone Fixnum
```

It seems that an object can report it accepts a message, but out right raise an exception.

I am trying to write a `deep_copy`. Is there a built-in one or can some code snippets already do that? If I need to decide whether something is clone-able, do I need to call it any way, and then `rescue` from the exception to know that it is not?

If an object will raise an exception, then (1) does it make sense to report `false`, or is it due to the interface requirement set forth by `Object`, and (2) can I actually tell any object to report false to `respond_to "foo"`?

Comment: A Fixnum responds to `clone`, so it makes sense for `1.respond_to?(:clone)` to return `true`. Consider: If you wrote a class with a method `def foo; raise "Error!" end` would you expect instances of that class to return `true` for `respond_to(:foo)`? I would. Whether or not it raises an error is immaterial. If it raised a NoMethodError that wouldn't make sense, but that's not the case here.

Comment: In other words, what is strange is not the behaviour of `respond_to?`, but the fact that `Kernel#clone` is defined just to return an error.

Comment: It might be interesting if you add the question: "Why is `clone` defined just to return an error? In what use case does it help?"

Comment: @sawa return ≠ raise

Comment: None of the methods of Fixnum mutates the object - may be there is no need to support `clone` as it will never be needed.

Comment: @mudasobwa I didn't use the term accurately, but I meant raising an exception. That is not a major issue.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Creating community wiki answer from Jordan's comment in question*</sup>

A `Fixnum` responds to `clone`, so it makes sense for `1.respond_to?(:clone)` to return `true`.

Consider, if you wrote a class with a method

```
def foo
   raise "Error!" 
end
```

would you expect instances of that class to return `true` for `respond_to(:foo)?`.  Answer is "Yes".

Whether or not it raises an error is immaterial. If it raised a `NoMethodError` that wouldn't make sense, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Is it true in good practice OOP, you wouldn't change what an object can respond to? And in fact, is there even a way to do that?  I think that's because once the interface is set, we don't want to alter it, or else it would violate class inheritance, interface inheritance, and polymorphism

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Fixnum.instance_method(:clone).owner
  #=> Kernel
Fixnum.ancestors
  #=> [Fixnum, Integer, Numeric, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Fixnum.included_modules
  #=> [Comparable, Kernel]
```

An instance of `Fixnum` responds to all of `Fixnum`'s instance methods, including those it has inherited from its ancestors. To ensure that no exception is raised when each of those methods (`clone` being one) is invoked on the Fixnum instance, a different design would be needed for the language.

Answer (score 1):

`respond_to? == true` means `NoMethodError` won't raise.

But other errors might raise.

If you want to do deep clone, use

```
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(obj_to_copy))
```

Comment: The [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Marshal.html) module is very useful, but a word of warning: `dump` does not raise an exception when its argument is an [immutable](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/mutable_and_immutable_objects.html) object. For example, `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(33)) #=> 33`, but `33` is not a "deep copy" of itself.

Comment: can the Marshal handle the case as in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/306392/what-is-a-proper-way-to-implement-object-cloning-with-deep-copy-using-generally?noredirect=1#comment642486_306392 which is, what if the object owns some other objects, vs just pointing to them (as in a node object of a graph)

Comment: You can answer that yourself. Try it!